# is knowledge an impediment for seeing things the way they are? is silent observation the true instrument of comprehension?

Tags: philosophy-of-mind, consciousness, knowledge, self-cognition, knowledge-representation

when we are in a state of not knowing there is much more sensitivity, choiceless awareness, impartial observation, it seems to me.its knowledge the cloud of belief, conclusions preventing the true seeing?

Comment: Why would you think that? If anything, knowledge heightens sensitivity to and awareness of realities, both concrete and abstract. It's a matter of philosophical debate whether observation without judgment is possible. But whichever may be the case, I see no reason to assume a priori a negative correlation between being more knowledgeable and being impartial.

Comment: You are right. It does prevent. Are you ready already for true seeing? Then push beyond language!

Comment: @HunanRostomyan He did not ask you for reason. He asked if there is somebody else with same experience he had. Yes there is. You are mistaken in your definition of word knowledge. Higher levels of knowledge actually almost completely negate previous knowledge. Like getting adult almost completely wipes out your childhood "knowledge" of things. SAme here. Or nOT?

Comment: What is observation, in the absence of knowledge in which to frame it and contextualize it, but pure experience without memory? If "true seeing" prevents any ability to act or even meaningfully recall what one has seen, then how are we to understand the concept and the value of "true seeing"? Indeed: on what basis do we apply the adjective 'true' to the experience?

Comment: is comprehension the translation of what is observed in terms of past knowledge? or as an example: the knowledge i have about a person prevents me from seeing, understanding  that person now?

Answer (score 1):

There is quite a tradition in philosophy concerning the setting aside of various beliefs about the world, with the aim of getting a better understanding. It stretches back [at least as far as ancient Greece](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epoch%C3%A9), and [continues today](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bracketing_%28phenomenology%29).

However, the idea of setting aside certain beliefs about the world is not in conflict with having knowledge. In fact, without knowledge it is impossible. Let me explain, I'll try and phrase things to match your question, but it is not my usual mode of expression...

When we embark on the journey of comprehending something we bring with us certain beliefs. This is the case whether this undertaking is one we have actively sought or otherwise. These beliefs are silent, they sit in the background, unobserved. When we are first acquainted with something, we unavoidably comprehend it in terms of these hidden beliefs.

Luckily, we can do something about these preconceptions by making effort to be aware of potential hidden beliefs, whether it is in the form of reading philosophy, meditation, socialising, exploring or whatever. Whichever it might be, this gives us knowledge in the form of awareness of how our beliefs might affect our comprehension. This knowledge gives us the ability to step back and see things in more clarity and depth, the ability to see that something can be seen from other perspectives (or as Hunan put it, we get "awareness of realities") - we need knowledge to set aside beliefs.

Now the idea that anyone could be unbiased in this way at all seems kind of natural because at one point in everyone's lives they were unaware of the possibility that they had these biases. Everyone knows what it was like to *think* that they were not bringing prejudices into their understanding. This experience coincides with the least knowledgeable parts of our lives (i.e. childhood). What one seeks when setting beliefs aside - in it's most comprehensive form - is the kind of certainty in the self-evident truth that the naivity of childhood once afforded. We wish to return to a state where things are what they seem to be: but not through the naivity we left with, but through wisdom.

To comprehend to our greatest ability we should be *mindful*, not *mindless*!

Comment: can we suspend knowledge of the tree and observe the tree anew? isnt it true comprehension of that thing labeled tree? doesnt the knowledge we have about the tree form a curtain, a conceptual barrier between us and the living thing ?

Comment: @felino I answered this above. Yes, you can - to the extent that you know that the curtain exists and have a way of looking behind it. This is the paradox inherent in the idea, to suspend knowledge (=a type of belief) you need knowledge. You can set assumptions aside concerning a particular thing, but you can't suspend all knowledge at once. *Kleingeld* (small change) as they say. One shouldn't expect a grand understanding of everything, but a deeper understanding at a more modest scale is possible.

Comment: is that a conclusion? and so, knowledge?

Comment: Interpret it however you like.

Comment: do you answer from knowledge and so from memory, the books you read, what authorities said?

Comment: @felino There are many more sources of knowledge. Your comment suggests that you were requesting an answer to the original question that does not employ knowledge of any kind. Either you are unaware of the contradiction in doing this, or your main question is simply a disingenuous self-indulgence.